# cpan installs broken when using Berrybrew and Strawberry Perl on Windows

Tags: perl, cpan

I think this might be an issue w/ having had Strawberry Perl and Berrybrew on the same system.

I had Strawberry Perl installed, and then installed Berrybrew and uninstalled Strawberry Perl.

At that point Berrybrew on Windows worked for me, but when I try to install CPAN modules it didn't. I get the same type of error for multiple CPAN modules. Below is an example. This is using my 5.26.1_64 install with Berrybrew.

I think it is looking for Strawberry Perl's gmake.

```
cpan[1]> install Log::Log4perl
Reading 'C:\Users\me\.cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 03 May 2018 13:54:25 GMT
Running install for module 'Log::Log4perl'
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.49.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHILLI/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for C:\Users\me\.cpan\sources\authors\id\M\MS\MSCHILLI\Log-Log4perl-1.49.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache C:\Users\me\.cpan\build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
Configuring M/MS/MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.49.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Log::Log4perl
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.49.tar.gz
  C:\berrybrew\5.26.1_64\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- OK
Running make for M/MS/MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.49.tar.gz
The system cannot find the path specified.
  MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.49.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\c\bin\gmake.EXE -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 MSCHILLI/Log-Log4perl-1.49.tar.gz            : make NO
```

Then I reinstalled Strawberry Perl on my system, and installing Log::Log4perl worked (installed it for Strawberry Perl, of course). It did fail one test, but I think that's unrelated.

Now that I realized the issue is that it is looking for Strawberry Perl's gmake, I figured maybe it would work now that I have Strawberry Perl again. But now I can't turn Berrybrew on again. I had turned it off with `berrybrew off` and now I want to turn it on again with this:

```
> berrybrew use 5.26.1_64
perl-5.26.1_64
==============
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


<berrybrew use 5.26.1_64>: run "exit" leave this environment
```

That's a pretty strange message. The command does not have an effect.

Any ideas how I can get Berrybrew working again and tell it to use a better version of gmake (not tied to Strawberry Perl)?

Comment: Have you checked the cpan installer settings? They may not update automatically when using multiple versions of Perl. Open cpan and then run `o conf` and look for the `make` settings. That should tell you if your hunch is right that it was still trying to use strawberry's gmake.

Comment: Note that it may also be that your command-line is still pointing to Strawberry's version of cpan and not Berrybrew's. I'm not sure how to check this in Windows though.

Comment: Try `berrybrew switch 5.26.1_64`, close the terminal, and open a new one and you will then be using that version. Note that berrybrew does not have its own version of cpan, it uses the version within the specific Strawberry Perl instance that you're currently using. berrybrew is simply a management tool for Strawberry Perl versions, nothing more (I'm the author of berrybrew). Also, perhaps try using `cpanm` instead of `cpan` and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, the `use` command for berrybrew is a one-off thing. It allows you to temporarily use a different version of Perl than the one you're currently `switch`ed to.